# Ajax sends empty parameters to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

So I am doing an `ajax` call from my view to a method in my controller but it keeps sending empty parameters. I print the values in console and the values are there, the correct ones but the controller has empty input parameters.

This is my `ajax` in my view

```
@model ModelLayer.Models.NotificationModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelLayer.Models.TableNotificationModel>()
        .Name("successfullData")
        .ToolBar(e =>
        {
           e.Custom().Text("Зачувај").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "customSaveButton", @class = "floatRight" });
        })
        //code shortened for brevity

$("#successfullData").on("click", "#customSaveButton", function () {
        var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model?.TableNotificationModel))');
        var saveType = 1;
        console.log("model", model)
        console.log("saveType", saveType)

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveFile", "Upload")',
            data: model,
            saveType: saveType
        })
    });
```

I call the function on the click of a Kendo grid button and send the data to the controller. I have the correct data in console

[image]

but my controller says otherwise

[image]

The model is empty, the `saveType` is 0. What am I missing here? Why am I sending empty parameters?

Comment: I think there might be several problems here.  First up can you show more of the C# method?  In AJAX that's performing a GET by default and your controller will need to match the same HTTP Verb.

If they are both GET, it will append contents of Model to the query string and you won't have a single object called model but all the properties of model

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer, I forgot the `method` property in the `ajax`. I added it and it sent the correct parameters - @dbmuller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AJAX that's performing a GET by default and your controller will need to match the same HTTP Verb. If they are both GET, it will append contents of Model to the query string and you won't have a single object called model but all the properties of model